# Relationship between the Standard Bases of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My question arises from trying to connect linear transformations between vector spaces with their 'square bracket' notation.

### Background

**Matrices:** Suppose $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is a linear transformation. Once we specify a basis each for the domain and codomain, we can unambiguously represent $f$ as a matrix, $\textbf A$.

**Standard Bases:**
Unless otherwise specified, we are working with "the" standard basis, which are represented as

$$\left \lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1 \\\ 0 \\\ 0 \\\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\\ 1 \\\ 0\\\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\\ 0 \\\ 1\\\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}, \dots \right\rbrace$$

in each dimension.

**Constructing (a candidate for) the Standard Basis**: Suppose we went back in history, before anyone knew or had defined what 'the standard basis' referred to.
We can pick *a* set of $n$ linearly independent vectors $\textbf e_1, \textbf e_2, \dots, \textbf e_n$ in $\mathbb R^n$, so that any vector $\textbf v\in \mathbb R^n$ can be uniquely represented as a linear combination of these:

$$\textbf v=v_1 \textbf e_1 + v_2 \textbf e_2 + \dots + \textbf v_ n e_n$$

Finally, we *make* this basis orthonormal by defining the inner product

$$
\langle \textbf v, \textbf w \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i w_i
$$

Henceforth, we write as $\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\\ a_2\\\ \vdots\end{bmatrix}$ to represent the vector $a_1 \textbf e_1 + a_2 \textbf e_2 + \dots + a_n \textbf e_n$.

### The Question:

I'm now confused about how to interpret an $m \times n$ matrix where $m \neq n$. Let $m<n$ without loss of generality.

1. Suppose $\lbrace {\textbf d}_1, \dots, {\textbf d}_m \rbrace$ is "the" standard basis for the codomain, $\mathbb R^m$. Is there any relationship between $\textbf e_i$ and ${\textbf d}_i$ aside from the fact that their *representations* in the 'square bracket' notation look similar?
2. If two mathematicians write down a matrix each, represented in terms of "the" standard bases for the domain and codomain, I would assume that they referring to the same linear transformation. Does this mean that we collectively agreed to call some specific set of linearly independent vectors in each dimension as the standard basis?  Which would imply that the standard bases for $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$ have no connection to each other aside from the fact that we have fixed them.

Comment: The standard basis is orthonormal. While it’s not the only basis like this, it’s straightforward and intuitive, as it builds off the idea of the Cartesian plane.

Comment: The matrix of a linear map between two finite-dimensional vector spaces is always given _relative to a pair of bases_, in the domain and in the codomain. For linear _operators_ (i.e. linear maps of a vector space into itself), the matrix of it is always given relative to a given basis. So, the "standard" bases are not preferred at all, you can work with any pair of bases (linear maps) or any basis (linear operator).

Comment: Note also in $\mathbb R^n$ you have the "standard basis" - in an arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector space you may not have any preferred basis to use as a "standard". (Let's say you have a plane in _Euclidean geometry_, You can of course pick any two non-colinear vectors and those will make up a basis, but there is no preferred basis at all!)

Comment: Thanks @StinkingBishop, I think that aligns with my understanding, and answers Question 1 of the post in the negative.

Comment: As for Question 2, I now suspect that it is not in the spirit of the matrix notation to specify *which* linear map we're talking about. Since there are no preferred standard bases, there is no preferred linear map that we could associate with a given matrix.

The alternative is to specify a preferred basis for each dimension, and lock them up someplace, kind of like the SI units. This would allow two mathematicians to agree on *which* particular linear map is being referred to.

Comment: That is correct. If you only have a matrix, you can only work out the linear map if you also specify or pre-arrange a pair of bases; then, the linear map will be uniquely defined by that matrix.